# Download Knowledge Directory documents of AquaLogic using api

Tags: c#, collaboration, portal, bea, plumtree

I am using IDK 6.0 in .net to download documents of Knowledge Directory. I have done lots of googling but found to api to do so.

Here are some of my reading materials:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13174_01/alui/idk/docs60/ndocs/index.html

http://translate.google.com.np/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://cn.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa%3FmessageID%3D9460557&ei=kl22Tr6UJourrAeu27nUAw&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CD0Q7gEwAw&prev=/search%3Fq%3Ddownload%2Bjar%2Bfile%2Bfor%2Bcom.plumtree.openkernel%26hl%3Den%26client%3Dfirefox-a%26sa%3DG%26rls%3Dorg.mozilla:en-US:official%26prmd%3Dimvnsfd

Is there any api of ALUI to download all documents of Knowledge Directory?

Thanks,

Prakash

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your Knowledge Directory, this process has some performance and practical considerations - but addressing your main point, you want to download all documents from your Knowledge Directory (KD).

Use the following:

Use the `IDocumentManager` interface to start, then call the `createQuery(int folderId)` method to get an instance of a query object.

You will be returned an `IDocumentQuery` object.

Keep in mind that the following defaults are set and will most likely need to be overrided in your case of getting *all* documents from the root folder:

> Factory method to create a document query on a specified document folder. The created query parameters default to start row=0, maximum of 100 results, show unapproved documents, sort by Document ID and no filters.

Assuming you have a reasonably large KD, I would recommend setting your filters to return documents based on date, at first using a `DateQueryFilter`, this will allow you to have a more manageable batch of files and object IDs. Knowing that you're working with an `IDocument` object type you can call `getDocument()` from there.